# Fedor's Lazy Load for Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-listview, android-gallery

I am using Fedor's Lazy Load, but I can't seem to adapt it to populate a gallery instead of a listview. My main problem seems to be to do with not having to inflate a separate layout. How do I pass the image results straight to the gallery?

This is my current getview which doesnt work

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
    ImageView image= new ImageView(context);
    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
  }
    return vi;
  }
```

and the error is a nullpointerexception within the gallery.

Any ideas on the appropriate adaptations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work using the following:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.galitem, null);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.galimage);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
    }

    return vi;

}
```

I set the parameters elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imgView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imgView = new ImageView(context);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    } else {
        imgView = convertView;
    }

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, imgView);

    return imgView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but things have moved on a little from here. I can now successfully start the activity, inflating a separate layout which includes only an ImageView for the gallery.  There are no errors, but the stub image is never replaced with an actual image. I will attempt to debug but if you know the answer it would be great.

Comment: You'll need to post your entire code then. I've used Fedor's lazy load class myself without any issues and it was pretty easy to adapt to my own needs.